# Entity framework - No code first option in asp.net form website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I want to utilize entity framework(code first from existing database) in my website. This video(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.) shows there are four options after adding ADO.NET Entity Data Model:

1. EF Designer from database
2. Empty EF Designer model
3. Empty Code First model, and
4. Code First from database

However in my project I only see two:

1. Generate from database, and
2. Empty model.

If I select Generate from database, the auto-created context file extends ObjectContext as opposed to DBContext. And all Entity Classes are thrown into the only context file as opposed to separate class files.

My Environment is:
asp.net form website project, .net 4.5;
Visual Studio 2012 professional;
Entity Framework 6.1.1 from NuGet.

This has been confusing me for a while and I didn't find anything similar here. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read far enough down on the site you linked to, it does explain why you aren't seeing the items from the video:

> We’re going to make use of the Entity Framework Tools for Visual Studio to help us generate some initial code to map to the database.

The reverse-engineering templates don't come with the Entity Framework, you need to install the additional tools to get them. You can download them from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Comment: Thanks Michael. This tool works. Now I can see all four options. Don't understand why the tutorial doesn't add the download link. It would be clearer and easier for programmers. Another question: In database first from existing database, there are model.context.tt and model.tt auto-generated. Under model.tt, there should be separate classes for each table per the video. But I see only one class containing all entity classes(each represents one db table) in the form of partial classes. How to generate separate classes?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. Is been a while since i used database first. But it all depends on which t4 templates you used, they may have changed since the video was released. It sounds like it just put all of your entity class into a single file, which is legal if confusing. Since you aren't supposed to edit those classes directly anyway it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I used EF6.x DbContext Generator. Separate classes look more logical and it'll be too big for one class if there are lots of tables. Anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: they are not one big class, that would be impossible. It sounds like it created one big *file* that contains all of your classes, which I admit isn't ideal, but for auto-generated code, works ok.